# Как лучше реализовать кастомные события в php?

Tags: php, алгоритм, события

*Задача*

Приветствую. Пусть у нас есть своеобразное голосование, такое, например, как здесь, на stackoverflow есть у любого вопроса или ответа:

<---

Например, я хочу удалять пост как только он набирает -10 голосов, добавлять его в избранные, как только он набирает +100 и архивировать спустя день после его появления.

*Моя реализация*

Рассмотрим сначала мою реализацию. Для решения проблемы с числом репутации, храним старое значение репутации (нужно для случая, когда репутация может меняться не только на +1 или -1, а сразу +10 или -7), а при любых ее изменениях проходим по условиям вида

```
if($old_reputation > -10 && $reputation <= -10) {
    deletePost();
    $old_reputation = $reputation;
}elseif($old_reputation < 100 && $reputation >= 100) {
    addToFeatured();
    $old_reputation = $reputation;
}
```

При этом обработку этих событий можно вынести в другой php-файл и вызывать его в cli, чтобы не тормозить основной скрипт.

Что же касается времени, то для этого придется либо завести демона, либо запускать ежеминутно крон и проверять время.

*Вопрос*

Есть ли более эффективная реализация? Нормальная ли вообще у меня для этого выбрана концепция?

Comment: не рассматриваете вариант с машиной состояний и шедуллером?

Comment: Смотрится не плохо, только не понятно что за условия у вас такие :< `if($old_reputation == -10 ) {` и `}elseif($old_reputation == 100) {` чем вас не устраивают?

Comment: @abu, вы про конечный автомат? Если так, то это слишком круто для такой мелкой задачи..

Comment: @Manitikyl, я же писал, чтобы можно было делать +10 баллов за раз, например. Если у поста прыгнет репутация с 99 до 109 сразу, то ваши условия не сработают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать для этого сервер очередей. Например, [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com).
Пишете обработчик, который будет в фоне ждать события в очереди, а при изменении рейтинга всегда бросаете в очередь событие, в котором передаёте id поста, старый и новый рейтинги. Консьюмер будет получать эту информацию и решать, что с постом делать дальше.

Comment: А как быть с событиями по времени — "спустя день после публикации архивировать пост"?

Comment: А вот это как раз лучше через планировщик делать. Запускать раз в несколько минут скрипт, который архивирует все записи старше суток